# Seperate sh command in multiple lines

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a sh command in jenkinsfile.

```
sh 'command1 command2'
```

How to write this in multiple lines?

```
sh '''
command1 \
command2
'''
```

or

```
sh '''
command1 &&
command2
'''
```

Comment: You should probably use neither if you are already specifying the command is multiple lines in Jenkins Pipeline for the shell interpreter.

Comment: What happens if you try one or the other?

Comment: @Matt Schuchard..... did not work. Already tried.

Comment: @DavidMaze I got the below error: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: login for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Answer (score 3):

The solution is :

```
sh """
command1 \\
command2 \\
"""
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should mix both:

```
sh '''
command1 && \
command2
'''
```

`&&` allows another command

`\` tells to shell to ignore the following character (the new line)

Comment: is not possible to separate commands?

sh ''command1"

sh "command2"

Answer (score 0):

What works best for me is (allowing variable expansion and readable, indented source-code):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sh -c '<<< EOL
  command 1
  command 2
  ...
'
```